# Unable to save variables from ActionClass after it is called

Tags: java, jsp, web, struts2, local-storage

I am using Struts2 in my web applicaiton. I have an ActionClass being called before my index.jsp is loaded. I want to get a variable `myVariable` to be saved to localStorage. but when ever I use a scriptlet I get a null value. I've tried adding an instance of that same object on the page but it still doesn't help. is there something I'm doing wrong here? I know there are other ways of doing this, what's one way around this problem?

the action class...

```
private String myVariable;

public String execute(){
    setMyVariable("ricky bobby");
}

public void setMyVariable(String myVariable) {
    this.myVariableD = myVariable;
}

public String getMyVariable() {
    return myVariable;
}
```

the jsp (snippet)....

```
<%@ page language="java" import="actionPackage.*"%>
<script>
     <% ActionClass ac = new ActionClass(); %>
     var acVar = "<%= ac.getMyVariable() %>";
     localStorage.setItem("acVar",acVar);
</script>
```

Im pretty sure it makes two seperate instances of it, but right now I just want to be able to save something in localStorage

Comment: Show your method in action class and jsp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

never mind!

Putting a `static` tag on the variable worked just fine for me.
Thankfully I only need it once so being static won't be a problem.